# Degree bounds Nullstellensatz: Multilinear polynomials

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra

Let $f, f_1, f_2, \ldots f_n$ be multi-linear polynomials. I am trying to understand conditions under which the variety of $f$ is a subset of the variety of $f_1, f_2,\ldots f_n.$

If I assume that these polynomials come from an algebraically closed field, then Hilbert's Nullstellensatz dictates that there must exist polynomials $\alpha_1, \alpha_2,\ldots, \alpha_n$ and an integer $L$ such that
$f^{L} = \alpha_1 f_1+\alpha_2 f_2 \ldots + \alpha_n f_n$

The question I have is the following: does the fact that the polynomials are multi-linear help in bounding the degrees/structure of $\alpha_i$ and the value of $L$?

If $f,f_i, i\in \{1,2,\ldots,n\}$ were linear, then there is a clear answer to this question (L=1, and setting $\alpha_i$ to be scalars suffices). I am wondering if there is a generalization of this idea to multi-linear polynomials.

Comment: [multilinear polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_polynomial) means the polynomial is linear in each of its variable

Comment: The keywords to search for are "effective Nullstellensatz". If I understand correctly the matter was more or less settled by Koll\'ar in the article _Sharp Effective Nullstellensatz_ (JAMS, 1988).